# How can I validate float interval with regexp?

Tags: regex

I want to check if a float number (actually java.math.BigDecimal) is in interval [0, 1.12]. Can I do that with regexp? The purpose of this is to validate a textfield.

Comment: I would convert the value to a number and then do normal number comparison.

Comment: IMO, you can't do it with regex, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regex you can validate a pattern, but not the meaning of the characters you are matching.

You can mimic this and make a pattern that fits all the valid values, but its a pain and not maintainable.

A Regex would look something like this (**Untested!!**)

```
/^(?:0|0\.\d+|1\.0\d*|1\.1\d*|1\.20*)$/
```

It would be better IMO to convert to a number and validate this way.

Comment: I played with it a little and used ^(?:0\.\d+|1|1\.0\d*|1\.11\d*|1\.120*)$

Comment: btw why did you put the slashed to the ends?

Comment: @Ondrej In some languages, e.g. Perl and PHP you need a regex delimiter, this can be the slashes, but also other characters. You haven't given a language, so I used Perl syntax.